# Using the Skytexture while masking with holdout

Tags: masking

I want to render a scene with a *Sky Texture* in the background, while masking out an object A with another object B by using the *Holdout* option under *Visibility > Mask* in the properties of object B.
But in order to get the masking, I need to check *Film > Transparent* which disables the *Sky Texture*.

Is there a way to have both things working? Masking the object and having the *Sky Texture*?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a smarter solution, the only one I can think of is the following: create a new View Layer. In it you disable all collections so that there is nothing visible to render. Under *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* > *Light* > *Other* you enable *Environment*.

[image: additional view layer]

Let's say you now have one called *ViewLayer* with the render scene including the holdout object and *ViewLayer_001* where all collections are disabled.

In the *Compositor* you need two *Render Layers*, one that is set to *ViewLayer* and the other is for the empty *ViewLayer_001*. After rendering you take an *Alpha Over* node and plug the *Env* output of *ViewLayer_001* in the first input and the *Image* output of *ViewLayer* in the second input. This way you can combine the foreground with the background.

Unfortunately you have to use two layers. I thought I remembered it differently, like you could use the *Env* output direct with a single layer, but the background is black where the objects are so that doesn't work. Maybe someone has a better solution.

[image: mixing view layers]